Print Image on Thermal Printer with MAUI over BLE
Hello People of the stack!
I recently bought a cheap thermal printer named pt-210 ; it should be working with using standard ESC-POS and thus described as free SDK
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Free-SDK-GOOJPRT-PT210-58MM-Mini_1600228662774.html
I have tested it with some PrintingApps in Googlestore and I can print texts and images!
Now I want to write my own project in MAUI to be able to print text and images as well.
I made some research in the web and could comeup with code to do my wish, but it succeed only for the text part and fails to print any image! (there is no error shown).
sofar here is my code, I am trying to take screenshoot and print it out
// take screenshoot and save it as PNG in the cachefolder
var path = FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory;
string fn = "ScanButton.png";
var fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fn);

var result = await ScanButton.CaptureAsync(); //take screenshoot of a UI controller (i.e Button)

using MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(); //create Mem Stream
await result.CopyToAsync(stream);                //copy the screenshoot into stream

await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(fullPath, stream.ToArray()); //saved in cash folder

//Load it from cash into a byte array 
byte[] data = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(fullPath);

using MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream(); //create another new stream
stream2.Write(SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE, 0, SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE.Length); //insert image mode
stream2.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
var bytes = stream2.ToArray();
if (serviceSelect != null && characteristicSelect != null)
{
    await characteristicSelect.WriteAsync(INIT);
    await characteristicSelect.WriteAsync(new byte[] { 0x0A });
    await characteristicSelect.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World"));
    await characteristicSelect.WriteAsync(new byte[] { 0x0A });
    await characteristicSelect.WriteAsync(new byte[] { 0x0A });
    await characteristicSelect.WriteAsync(bytes);

I already tried both
//public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = { 0x1B, 0x2A, 33, (byte)255, 0 };
public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = { 0x1B, 0x2A, 33, 255, 3 };

I also tried printing witha and without
public static byte[] INIT = { 0x1B, 0x40 };

the Thermal Printer print only the text and no image is shown, I suspect that I am missing some steps!
I would appreciate any advice!
thnx in advance

you can't just write the bytes of a png to jpeg to the printer and expect it to print, unless the printer has specific support for that.  You will need to convert the image to a b/w bitmap of the correct resolution and send the raw image data to the printer.  This has been discussed multiple times
